# Customized header

Tags: php, wordpress

I am making a wordpress theme. Normally I have a header file, but I want it to slightly differ from page to page, that is I want it to contain additional text that is different for each page (and is not general, like an article title, but it's like on one page I need a title, on the other a link, etc.)

What is the best practice to do this? Change the text from JavaScript? I don't want to have separate header files, just to somehow change text in a div included in this header file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do something for 'ya?

```
<?php
   if (function_exists('is_tag') && is_tag()) {
      single_tag_title("Tag archive fot &quot;"); echo '&quot; - '; }
   elseif (is_archive()) {
      wp_title(''); echo ' archive - '; }
   elseif (!(is_404()) && (is_single()) || (is_page())) {
      wp_title(''); echo ' - '; }
   elseif (is_404()) {
      echo 'Whoops, nothing here! - '; }
   if (is_home()) {
      bloginfo('name'); echo ' - '; bloginfo('description'); }
   else {
       bloginfo('name'); }
   if ($paged>1) {
      echo ' - page '. $paged; }
?>
```

With [conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) you can server different stuff for certain pages.

/Paul

Comment: Wow, dude, you're an absolute genius, this is exactly what I needed! Thank you, thank you, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how much change is needed. I am guessing that you can have a function or a different file included in header.php

A very common way to approach this would be to have different header files in your theme. By default you should have a header.php file. You could also create files like header-**name**.php and use the optional parameter for the [get_header](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header) function.

In your themes the header file is included by using the get_header function but usually with no parameter. But if you use it like this:

```
get_header('name');
```

the custom file header-name.php will be used. You could as well use different pages templates (see [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates)) for some sections and each could include a different header file using the method described above.

Comment: This sounds like a fine solution, but the change to header files is not that big, while on the other hand it's needed for almost every page, which would mean that I would need separate header files for almost every page.

Comment: in that case you can have a function in your functions.php file found inside the theme's directory that returns a different part of content depending on the differences you are interested in (like the post id, the category etc)

Comment: And what is the best way to differentiate between pages?

Comment: I am guessing that this depends a lot on your system. On how dynamic it is (if you publish every day or it has a fixed structure) or how big are the differences. You could as well write a plugin that stores in the database a relationship between post id and header text.. list them in the admin area by extending WP_List_Table.. and allow a management on this